# Path integral of vector field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Let $\gamma$ be the path in $\Bbb{R^3}$ parametrized as **x**$(t)=(cos(2t), sin(t), sin(2t))$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

Let **A** be the vector field with components $(x,-y^2,0)$, where $(x,y,z)$ are Cartesian coordinates in $\Bbb{R^3}$.
Evaluate

$\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}$ **A**$\cdot$ *d***s**

I think I'm meant to find ||**x**'(t)|| which I'm getting as $\sqrt{4sin^{2}2t +cos^{2}t +4cos^{2}2t}$ which I'm not sure is even right or if am just meant to find **x**'(t)...?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You have to find path integral of a vector field and not a scalar function. So you should fine $r'(t)$ and do dot product with the vector field $A$ and integrate.

Comment: @MathLover thank you!